# Tengo la siguiente BB.DD y me piden "Obtener para todos los departamentos ubicados en Madrid su nombre y número de empleados"

Tags: mysql, sql, datatables, mysql-workbench

He realizado la siguiente consulta pero no consigo que me filtre solo los departamentos ubicados en MADRID

```
SELECT nomDepar, count(idEmpleado)
 FROM empleados x , departamentos y
 WHERE x.idDepar=y.idDepar IN 
  (SELECT x.idDepar=y.idDepar 
     FROM departamentos 
     WHERE idSede IN 
      (SELECT idSede FROM sedes WHERE ciudadSede='Madrid')
   )
GROUP BY nomDepar;
```

Alguna idea de que me falla para que filtre por "MADRID"

Las tablas para la consulta serian:

[image: Tabla Empelados]
[image: Tabla Departamentos]
[image: Tabla Sedes]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select d.nomDepar, count(e.idEmpleado)
from empleado e 
inner join  departamento d on e.idDepar = d.idDepar 
inner join sede s on s.idSede = d.idSede
where s.ciudadSede = 'Madrid'
group by d.nomDepar;
```

En la **cláusula from** se hace la junta con todas las tablas de interés:

- Empleado
- Departamento
- Sede

A través de los campos que las relacionan, para esto se usa la **cláusula inner join**.
Se aplica un **where** que filtre de esta junta de tablas todos los departamentos cuya sede está en Madrid, se agrupa por el nombre de los departamentos y en la **cláusula select** se muestra el nombre de los departamentos y se cuenta con la **función de agregación count** todos los empleados de ese departamento.